# I am looking to find customers repurchase frequency in SQL from their first purchase date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**I am trying to find the customer's repurchase rates from their first order date. For example, for 2016, how many customer purchased 1X in days 1-365 from their initial purchase, how many purchased twice etc.**

I have a transaction_detail table which looks like below:

```
txn_date Customer_ID  Transaction_Number    Sales 
1/2/2019    1           12345                $10
4/3/2018    1           65890                $20
3/22/2019   3           64453                $30
4/3/2019    4           88567                $20
5/21/2019   4           85446                $15
1/23/2018   5           89464                $40
4/3/2019    5           99674                $30
4/3/2019    6           32224                $20
1/23/2018   6           46466                $30
1/20/2018   7           56558                $30
```

I am able to find the customers who have shopped in 2016 and how many times have they repurchased in 2016, **but I need to find the customer who have shopped in 2016 and how many times have they come back from their first purchase date.**

I need a starting point for the query, I am not sure how to build this logic in my SQL code.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using the below query:

```
WITH by_year
AS (SELECT
  Customer_ID,
  to_char(txn_date, 'YYYY') AS visit_year
FROM table
GROUP BY Customer_ID, to_char(txn_date, 'YYYY')),
with_first_year
AS (SELECT
  Customer_ID,
  visit_year,
  FIRST_VALUE(visit_year) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY visit_year) AS first_year
FROM by_year),
with_year_number
AS (SELECT
  Customer_ID,
  visit_year,
  first_year,
  (visit_year - first_year) AS year_number
FROM with_first_year)
SELECT
  first_year  AS first_year,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_6,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_7,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_8,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year_number = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS year_9
FROM with_year_number
GROUP BY first_year
ORDER BY first_year
```

Comment: hi @Somya please include sample data from all tables/mviews being queried along with the desired output; just helps to understand the requirement better.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions and aggregation:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(customer_id), max(customer_id)
from (select customer_id, count(*) as cnt
      from (select td.*,
                   min(txn_date) over (partition by Customer_ID) as min_txn_date
            from transaction_detail td
           ) td
      where txn_date >= min_txn_date and txn_date < min_txn_date + interval '365' day
      group by customer_id
     ) c
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

Comment: this is giving me an error:
ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
01873. 00000 -  "the leading precision of the interval is too small"
*Cause:    The leading precision of the interval is too small to store the
           specified interval.
*Action:   Increase the leading precision of the interval or specify an
           interval with a smaller leading precision.
Error at Line: 11 Column: 77

Comment: I have updated the query which I am using based on your query in the original question

Comment: @Somya . . . You can replace `min_txn_date + interval '365' day` with `min_txn_date + 365`, but that should not be necessary.

Comment: this query does not give the results I want :(

Answer (score 0):

So as per my understanding, you want to know the count of the distinct person who first purchased in 2016 and repurchased after one year or more from date of purchase.

```
Select * from
(
  Select customer_id, 
         Floor(months_between(txn_date, lead_txn_date)/12) as num_years
  From
  (
   Select customer_id, 
          txn_date, 
          row_number() over (partition by Customer_ID order by txn_date) as rn, 
          lead(txn_date) over (partition by Customer_ID order by txn_date) as lead_txn_date
     From your_table
  )
    Where txn_date >= date '2016-01-01' 
      and txn_date < date '2017-01-01'
      and rn = 1
      And months_between(txn_date, lead_txn_date) >= 12
)
Pivot
(
  Count(1) for num_year in (1,2,3,4)
)
```

Ultimately, we are finding the number of years between first and second purchase of the customer. And first purchase must be in 2016.

Cheers!!

Comment: I need to find the customer who have shopped in 2016 and how many times have they come back from their **first purchase date. their first purchase date would have been any date in 2016 so 365 days from that date.

Comment: That is why it is good practise to provide sample data alongwith expected output.

Comment: I am not sure how to put in in results, also the query does not give me any result